# 'Parameter is not valid.' when trying to retrive image from database MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, image, winforms

I'm working on winForms a project where the user will be able to draw a signature with his cursor and save it in a database.

This is how I'm saving it:

```
ExecuteQuery("INSERT INTO signatures (name, signature) VALUES ('"+ TXTname.Text +"','"+ signature +"')");
```

(this is not giving me any error)

keep in mind signature column type is blob.

Then, I want the user to retrive his signature from the database to a picturebox, this is how I'm **trying** to do it:

```
 DBconnection.Open();

                Image signature;

                string query = "SELECT * FROM signatures WHERE name = '" + CMBnames.Text + "'";

                var queryCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, DBconnection);

                reader = queryCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    byte[] img = (byte[])(reader["SIGNATURE"]);
                    if (img == null)
                    {
                        CMBnames.Text = "error";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);

                        pictureBox2.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                    }
                }

DBconnection.Close();
```

But I get this error 'Parameter is not valid.' here:

```
pictureBox2.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tip: Please avoid `select *` in query, you column names instead. High chance there’s some issue with the data, either you are selecting wring column from db or the data is not valid in the column

Comment: Please read http://bobby-tables.com - the reason I'm recommending it is because that is a particularly awful way of writing Sal that, if you use it in a serious capacity on an important computer system, will get you hacked, or fired, or both. You should never again in your entire professional life, write an SQL like those there (and helpfully, you'll need to use parameters to effectively and efficiently save an image in a db, though I would also say not to do that either- save the file on disk and save the path in the db)

Comment: thanks guys, this is only a hobby of mine so yeah, I'm not really good with MySql. I'll try to make it better.

Comment: @viveknuna I tried selecting the only the column name, same error.

Answer (score 0):

If `signature` is a `byte[]` then `'"+ signature +"'` will generate the literal string `'System.Byte[]'`. This is not a valid image, and reading it back will produce the error you're seeing.

You need to use command parameters, not string concatenation:

```cs
using var cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO signatures (name, signature)
    VALUES (@name, @signature);", DBconnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TXTname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@signature", signature);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```